# Invertible linear transformation on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let T be a linear transformation on a vector space V such that $T^2 =\operatorname{id}$ and $T ≠ \operatorname{id}$.

Let
$U = \{v ∈ V : T(v) = v\}$ and $W = \{v ∈ V : T(v) = -v\}$. Show that

$$V = U + W $$

I guess it's related to something about the above two identities, which obviously imply that $T$ is invertible, but I cannot make progress.

Comment: By "id" do you mean the $n$th order identity matrix, $\underline{\underline{I}}_{n}$? Please clarify.

Comment: @K.defaoite The OP is talking about linear transformations, not matrices. $\operatorname{id}$ is the identity map from $V$ to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in V$, then it is decomposable as 
$$ v= (v+T(v))/2 + (v-T(v))/2$$
You can easily show that the two summands are in $U$ and $W$, and that shows the claim.

Comment: How can we show that two summands of v=(v+T(v))/2+(v−T(v))/2 are in U and W?

Comment: Just apply $T$ and use linearity