# linear transformation on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T be a linear transformation on a vector space V such that T2=id and T≠id.

Let U={v∈V:T(v)=v} and W={v∈V:T(v)=−v}. Show that

V=U+W

Here,

Let v∈V, then it is decomposable as
v=(v+T(v))/2+(v−T(v))/2

This looks like some part of this decomposition belong to U and W, so that V=U+W satisfy.

But I'm not sure which part belong to U and whcih part belong to W...

Comment: If you didn’t understand [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3645526/265466) to your previous question, you should ask for clarification in a comment instead of posting a new question.

Comment: Please use MathJax to formulate your posts :)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

$T[(v+T(v))/2]=(T(v)+T(T(v)))/2=(T(v)+v)/2=(v+T(v))/2$

and

$T[(v-T(v))/2]=(T(v)-T(T(v))/2=(T(v)-v)/2=-(v-T(v))/2$

Answer (score 0):

If $T^2 - I = 0$

$T$ has two eigenvalues, $\pm 1$

And any vector can be decomposed into the component from the eigenspace associated with $1$ and the eigenspace associated with $-1$

$v = \alpha u + \beta w$

$T(v) = \alpha u - \beta w\\
\frac {v + T(v)}{2} = \frac {\alpha u + \beta w + \alpha u- \beta w}{2} = \alpha u\\
\frac {v - T(v)}{2} = \frac {\alpha u + \beta w - \alpha u+ \beta w}{2} = \beta w$